# Solr Query using Facet missing the special characters and its showing in split values

Tags: solr, solrj, facet

I have added the documents into the solr using the solr client java API
  Consider 2 fields,
     field1     | field2
   aaa@test.com    value1

I was able to successfully index the documents.

In the solr admin UI when i executed the query i was able to see 1 record with these above values.

In the admin UI I have enabled Facet on this field and try to execute the query.
   But i got result in splitted values as shown below

Checked the facet checkbox and in the facet.field = owner and then clicked execute query got the below result

```
"facet_counts":{
"facet_queries":{},
"facet_fields":{
  "owner":[
    "com",1,
    "test",1,
    "aaa",1]},
"facet_ranges":{},
"facet_intervals":{},
"facet_heatmaps":{}}}
```

If you see in the above result i got splited string how to get that in single output
   aaa@test.com , 1

Please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The facets are generated from the tokens for the field. If you're using a text based field with a tokenizer attached, the value will be split into multiple tokens.

To get the behavior you want, use a `string` field and reindex your content to that field. Use a `copyField` instruction if you still want to be able to search with partial content against the field, and facet on the new field instead.